# Searching through an Array and replacing some of its values

Tags: php, arrays, search, replace

I have a preg_match_all that is generating an array of urls from a string. The array resembles:

```
$url[0] = "http://www.siteone.com";
$url[1] = "http://www.sitetwo.com";
$url[2] = "http://www.sitethree.com/example1";
$url[3] = "http://www.sitefour.com";
$url[4] = "http://www.sitethree.com/example2";
$url[5] = "http://www.sitefive";
$url[6] = "http://www.sitesix";
$url[7] = "http://www.siteseven";
$url[8] = "http://www.sitethree.com/example3";
```

However, I need to be able to search through the #url array to change the value when it contains "http://www.sitethree.com" and set this particular value in the array to "no value". So that once this process was applied,, it would the array would look like this:

```
$url[0] = "http://www.siteone.com";
$url[1] = "http://www.sitetwo.com";
$url[2] = "no value";
$url[3] = "http://www.sitefour.com";
$url[4] = "no value";
$url[5] = "http://www.sitefive";
$url[6] = "http://www.sitesix";
$url[7] = "http://www.siteseven";
$url[8] = "no value";
```

I have tried numerous variations of preg_match_all and if statements within loops but just couldn't get it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($url as &$value) {
  if (strpos($value, 'http://www.sitethree.com') === 0) {
    $value = 'no value';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$url = array_map(function($v) {
    return strpos($v, 'http://www.sitethree.com') === false ? $v : 'no value';
}, $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($url as $id => $link){
    if(strstr($link, 'sitethree.com')){
         $url[$id] = 'no value';
    }
}
print_r($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing it is this:

```
foreach($url as $key => $value)
{
  if(stristr($value, "http://www.sitethree.com"))
  {
    $url[$key] = "no value";
  }
}
```